# Terminate recursion after reaching certain condition

Tags: matlab, recursion

I've been experimenting with a Sudoku solver using recursion. The problem I've encountered it that the recursive function after finding the right solution will not terminate, but goes on until every number is tested at every position.

How do I terminate such loop in Matlab? Error condition 'error('...') within the function can break the execution, but is by no means a good solution to my problem.

Here is a sample code for similar recursion, producing all possible 2 element vectors for numbers from 1 to 4. I would like it to stop when both numbers are equal to 2.

```
%possible moves at each position
moveMat = zeros([1,2])+3;

lineInput = zeros([1,2]);

%start recursion
recurNumbers(moveMat, 0, lineInput)

function recurNumbers(moveMat, position, lineVariable)

position = position + 1;

%if all numbers are equal to 2 then try to exit the function
if ~all(lineVariable == 2)

    %if all numbers are not equal to 2, try other combination
    if position < length(lineVariable)+1
        for move = 0 : moveMat(position)

            moveMat(position) = move;
            lineVariable(position) = lineVariable(position) + 1;
            recurNumbers(moveMat,position,lineVariable)
            disp(lineVariable)

        end
    end

else

    disp(lineVariable)
    return

end
end
```

Now it will print the vector '[2 2]' twice, which indicates that it recognised the condition, but the 'return' will not do what I imagined it to do.

Comment: Try using the debugger to step into you function; this should help you find the problem. In particular, you call the recursive function within a loop, so it will be called for every iteration of the loop regardless of the result! You should put a break condition within the loop

Comment: To emphasise what Zep says, you literally want to use `break` within the loop, not `error` as you suggest in your question.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but putting 'if all(lineVariable == 2); break; end' within the loop is still not stopping it.

Comment: @RecBCD Your question is not clear. The algorithm you wrote does not "solve sudoku": it tries to increase lineVariable unti is is equal to [2 2]. Try to explain what THIS algorithm does, not what is your largest scheme.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although it is not very clear to me what you are trying to achieve, I assume that the following function meets your stopping criterion.

```
function exit_fl = recurNumbers(moveMat, position, lineVariable)

exit_fl = 0;
if (all(lineVariable == 2)) 
  % Show the result and exit
  disp(lineVariable)
  exit_fl = 1;

else
  position = position + 1;
    %if all numbers are not equal to 2, try other combination
    if position < length(lineVariable)+1
        for move = 0 : moveMat(position)

            moveMat(position) = move;
            lineVariable(position) = lineVariable(position) + 1;
            % Receive the exit status of your function
            ex_fl = recurNumbers(moveMat,position,lineVariable);
            if (ex_fl == 1)
              % If the criterion was met, then stop
              exit_fl = 1;
              return
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

Comment: It still will not stop the recursion. To make it clear, I was working on a Sudoku solver, that would attempt to try every number from 1 to 9 at every free position. The idea is to terminate the function once the sudoku was solved. Otherwise it will go on even when sudoku is solved.

Comment: @Aristotelis you should probably add a `return` after the `exit_fl = 1` within the loop to stop the cycle

Comment: Thanks for that Zep! Removed it by mistake. @RecBCD Could you have a look again?